# How to connect to Microsoft Azure once I have the Azure Resources information/credentials. Do I need to download a specific client?

Tags: azure

This may be an extremely basic task for those of you who have experiencing configuring and using Azure. I received Azure Resources information/credentials as you see below. **I have totally changed values in the information below for confidentiality reasons** but the information below will give you an idea of the type of credentials information that I have received to connect to Microsoft Azure.

**Azure Resources information**

**Storage account**

**Account url:** https://ebyjskbp.blob.core.windows.net/

**Container:** ebyjskykc

**SAS Key:**

?ca=2017-10-11&ss=behj&srt=yte&sp=jkl&se=2023-06-23T12:42:36Z&st=2020-02-23T10:32:433Z&spr=https&sig=aFghPD4FGwhGW4hsGR3BFFGnFgheBeDh3HD4GhG0gHF%3D

**Blobs:**

**SQL Database**

**Server:** ebyjsghjshtj.database.windows.net

**Database:** ebyjseg

**Username:** ghklyemw

**Password:** Gahsjji_3647

Do I need to use a specific client to connect using those credentials? I know for example that if I receive FTP credentials, all I need to do is to download FileZilla or an equivalent FTP client and connect using the SFTP protocol. I also know that if I receive SSH credentials and I am using Windows, all I need to do is to download PuTTY and use the corresponding credentials to connect to the server. If I am on UNIX or Mac, I use the `ssh` command directly from the terminal. But in the case of Microsoft Azure, now that I have received the Azure Resources information or credentials, which client should I use to connect to Azure? Or is it a built-in Windows client such as the Remote Desktop Connection shown in the screen below?:

[image]

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

Maybe I need to install Azure Data Studio and then use the credentials I received to connect?

**UPDATE 2:**

It looks like this YouTube video explains what I need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-7fjR3yPUVU (Load data from Azure Blog storage into Azure SQL | Data Exposed)

Answer (score 0):

In 2 minutes and 43 seconds, this video explains all I needed to know. I could connect to the Azure database successfully:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Td_pYlRraQE (How to connect to Azure SQL Database from Azure Data Studio | Data Exposed)